# How can I make my JQuery run again when using goBack() in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mern, use-effect

I have react app using Switch of react-router-dom. When people click they can see the profile of a person in full, but I want a goBack button, so I did this.

```
const onClick = () => {
    return history.goBack();
}
```

The problem is, when I go back to the last page, the jQuery libraries I'm using don't work, and even some code I'm using in useEffect. I'm using forceRefresh in my Router so every time I go to another page in the Switch I can see the animations an load the actions, is not the best solution but has been working so far.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding the jQuery file, maybe this helps. This file is called in index.html of the public folder

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/custom.js" async defer></script>
```

Code:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
      function mmenuInit() {
        var wi = $(window).width();
        if (wi <= '1099') {
          $('.mmenu-init').remove();
          $('#navigation')
            .clone()
            .addClass('mmenu-init')
            .insertBefore('#navigation')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .removeClass('style-1 style-2')
            .find('ul, div')
            .removeClass(
              'style-1 style-2 mega-menu mega-menu-content mega-menu-section'
            )
            .removeAttr('id');
          $('.mmenu-init').find('ul').addClass('mm-listview');
          $('.mmenu-init').find('.mobile-styles .mm-listview').unwrap();

          $('.mmenu-init').mmenu(
            {
              counters: true,
            },
            {
              // configuration
              offCanvas: {
                pageNodetype: '#wrapper',
              },
            }
          );

          var mmenuAPI = $('.mmenu-init').data('mmenu');
          var $icon = $('.mmenu-trigger .hamburger');

          $(document).on('click', '.mmenu-trigger', function () {
            mmenuAPI.open();
          });
        }
        $('.mm-next').addClass('mm-fullsubopen');
      }
      mmenuInit();
      $(window).resize(function () {
        mmenuInit();
      });
    });


    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
      var transparentHeaderHeight = $('.transparent-header').outerHeight();
      $('.transparent-header-spacer').css({
        height: transparentHeaderHeight,
      });
    });




    $('.ripple-effect, .ripple-effect-dark').on('click', function (e) {
      var rippleDiv = $('<span class="ripple-overlay">'),
        rippleOffset = $(this).offset(),
        rippleY = e.pageY - rippleOffset.top,
        rippleX = e.pageX - rippleOffset.left;

      rippleDiv
        .css({
          top: rippleY - rippleDiv.height() / 2,
          left: rippleX - rippleDiv.width() / 2,
          // background: $(this).data("ripple-color");
        })
        .appendTo($(this));

      window.setTimeout(function () {
        rippleDiv.remove();
      }, 800);
    });


    $('.switch, .radio').each(function () {
      var intElem = $(this);
      intElem.on('click', function () {
        intElem.addClass('interactive-effect');
        setTimeout(function () {
          intElem.removeClass('interactive-effect');
        }, 400);
      });
    });


    $(window).on('load', function () {
      $('.button.button-sliding-icon')
        .not('.task-listing .button.button-sliding-icon')
        .each(function () {
          var buttonWidth = $(this).outerWidth() + 30;
          $(this).css('width', buttonWidth);
        });
    });

    $('.bookmark-icon').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('bookmarked');
    });

    $('.bookmark-button').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('bookmarked');
    });


    $('a.close')
      .removeAttr('href')
      .on('click', function () {
        function slideFade(elem) {
          var fadeOut = { opacity: 0, transition: 'opacity 0.5s' };
          elem.css(fadeOut).slideUp();
        }
        slideFade($(this).parent());
      });



    // Closing function
    function close_user_dropdown() {
      $('.header-notifications').removeClass('active');
    }

    // Closes notification dropdown on click outside the conatainer
    var mouse_is_inside = false;

    $('.header-notifications').on('mouseenter', function () {
      mouse_is_inside = true;
    });
    $('.header-notifications').on('mouseleave', function () {
      mouse_is_inside = false;
    });

    $('body').mouseup(function () {
      if (!mouse_is_inside) close_user_dropdown();
    });

    // Close with ESC
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        close_user_dropdown();
      }
    });

    if ($('.status-switch label.user-invisible').hasClass('current-status')) {
      $('.status-indicator').addClass('right');
    }

    $('.status-switch label.user-invisible').on('click', function () {
      $('.status-indicator').addClass('right');
      $('.status-switch label').removeClass('current-status');
      $('.user-invisible').addClass('current-status');
    });

    $('.status-switch label.user-online').on('click', function () {
      $('.status-indicator').removeClass('right');
      $('.status-switch label').removeClass('current-status');
      $('.user-online').addClass('current-status');
    });


    // Wrapper Height (window height - header height)
    function wrapperHeight() {
      var headerHeight = $('#header-container').outerHeight();
      var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight() - headerHeight;
      $(
        '.full-page-content-container, .dashboard-content-container, .dashboard-sidebar-inner, .dashboard-container, .full-page-container'
      ).css({ height: windowHeight });
      $('.dashboard-content-inner').css({ 'min-height': windowHeight });
    }

    // Enabling Scrollbar
    function fullPageScrollbar() {
      $('.full-page-sidebar-inner, .dashboard-sidebar-inner').each(function () {
        var headerHeight = $('#header-container').outerHeight();
        var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight() - headerHeight;
        var sidebarContainerHeight = $(this)
          .find('.sidebar-container, .dashboard-nav-container')
          .outerHeight();

        // Enables scrollbar if sidebar is higher than wrapper
        if (sidebarContainerHeight > windowHeight) {
          $(this).css({ height: windowHeight });
        } else {
          $(this).find('.simplebar-track').hide();
        }
      });
    }

    // Init
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
      wrapperHeight();
      fullPageScrollbar();
    });
    wrapperHeight();
    fullPageScrollbar();

    // Sliding Sidebar
    $('.enable-filters-button').on('click', function () {
      $('.full-page-sidebar').toggleClass('enabled-sidebar');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.filter-button-tooltip').removeClass('tooltip-visible');
    });

    /*  Enable Filters Button Tooltip */
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      $('.filter-button-tooltip')
        .css({
          left: $('.enable-filters-button').outerWidth() + 48,
        })
        .addClass('tooltip-visible');
    });

    // Avatar Switcher
    function avatarSwitcher() {
      var readURL = function (input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.profile-pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      };

      $('.file-upload').on('change', function () {
        readURL(this);
      });

      $('.upload-button').on('click', function () {
        $('.file-upload').click();
      });
    }
    avatarSwitcher();

    // Dashboard Nav Submenus
    $('.dashboard-nav ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
      if ($(this).closest('li').children('ul').length) {
        if ($(this).closest('li').is('.active-submenu')) {
          $('.dashboard-nav ul li').removeClass('active-submenu');
        } else {
          $('.dashboard-nav ul li').removeClass('active-submenu');
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active-submenu');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });

    // Responsive Dashbaord Nav Trigger
    $('.dashboard-responsive-nav-trigger').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

      var dashboardNavContainer = $('body').find('.dashboard-nav');

      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(dashboardNavContainer).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(dashboardNavContainer).removeClass('active');
      }

      $('.dashboard-responsive-nav-trigger .hamburger').toggleClass(
        'is-active'
      );
    });

    // Fun Facts
    function funFacts() {
      /*jslint bitwise: true */
      function hexToRgbA(hex) {
        var c;
        if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
          c = hex.substring(1).split('');
          if (c.length == 3) {
            c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
          }
          c = '0x' + c.join('');
          return (
            'rgba(' +
            [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') +
            ',0.07)'
          );
        }
      }

      $('.fun-fact').each(function () {
        var factColor = $(this).attr('data-fun-fact-color');

        if (factColor !== undefined) {
          $(this)
            .find('.fun-fact-icon')
            .css('background-color', hexToRgbA(factColor));
          $(this).find('i').css('color', factColor);
        }
      });
    }
    funFacts();

    // Notes & Messages Scrollbar
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
      var winwidth = $(window).width();
      if (winwidth > 1199) {
        // Notes
        $('.row').each(function () {
          var mbh = $(this).find('.main-box-in-row').outerHeight();
          var cbh = $(this).find('.child-box-in-row').outerHeight();
          if (mbh < cbh) {
            var headerBoxHeight = $(this)
              .find('.child-box-in-row .headline')
              .outerHeight();
            var mainBoxHeight =
              $(this).find('.main-box-in-row').outerHeight() -
              headerBoxHeight +
              39;

            $(this)
              .find('.child-box-in-row .content')
              .wrap(
                '<div class="dashboard-box-scrollbar" style="max-height: ' +
                  mainBoxHeight +
                  'px" data-simplebar></div>'
              );
          }
        });

        // Messages Sidebar
        // var messagesList = $(".messages-inbox").outerHeight();
        // var messageWrap = $(".message-content").outerHeight();
        // if ( messagesList > messagesWrap) {
        //  $(messagesList).css({
        //      'max-height': messageWrap,
        //  });
        // }
      }
    });

    // Mobile Adjustment for Single Button Icon in Dashboard Box
    $('.buttons-to-right').each(function () {
      var btr = $(this).width();
      if (btr < 36) {
        $(this).addClass('single-right-button');
      }
    });

    // Small Footer Adjustment
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
      var smallFooterHeight = $('.small-footer').outerHeight();
      $('.dashboard-footer-spacer').css({
        'padding-top': smallFooterHeight + 45,
      });
    });

    // Auto Resizing Message Input Field
    /* global jQuery */
    jQuery.each(jQuery('textarea[data-autoresize]'), function () {
      var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;

      var resizeTextarea = function (el) {
        jQuery(el)
          .css('height', 'auto')
          .css('height', el.scrollHeight + offset);
      };
      jQuery(this)
        .on('keyup input', function () {
          resizeTextarea(this);
        })
        .removeAttr('data-autoresize');
    });


    function userMenuScrollbar() {
      $('.header-notifications-scroll').each(function () {
        var scrollContainerList = $(this).find('ul');
        var itemsCount = scrollContainerList.children('li').length;
        var notificationItems;

        // Determines how many items are displayed based on items height
        /* jshint shadow:true */
        if (scrollContainerList.children('li').outerHeight() > 140) {
          var notificationItems = 2;
        } else {
          var notificationItems = 3;
        }

        // Enables scrollbar if more than 2 items
        if (itemsCount > notificationItems) {
          var listHeight = 0;

          $(scrollContainerList)
            .find('li:lt(' + notificationItems + ')')
            .each(function () {
              listHeight += $(this).height();
            });

          $(this).css({ height: listHeight });
        } else {
          $(this).css({ height: 'auto' });
          $(this).find('.simplebar-track').hide();
        }
      });
    }

    // Init
    userMenuScrollbar();


    /* global tippy */
    tippy('[data-tippy-placement]', {
      delay: 100,
      arrow: true,
      arrowType: 'sharp',
      size: 'regular',
      duration: 200,

      // 'shift-toward', 'fade', 'scale', 'perspective'
      animation: 'shift-away',

      animateFill: true,
      theme: 'dark',

      // How far the tooltip is from its reference element in pixels
      distance: 10,
    });


    var accordion = (function () {
      var $accordion = $('.js-accordion');
      var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.js-accordion-header');

      // default settings
      var settings = {
        // animation speed
        speed: 400,

        // close all other accordion items if true
        oneOpen: false,
      };

      return {
        // pass configurable object literal
        init: function ($settings) {
          $accordion_header.on('click', function () {
            accordion.toggle($(this));
          });

          $.extend(settings, $settings);

          // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
          if (settings.oneOpen && $('.js-accordion-item.active').length > 1) {
            $('.js-accordion-item.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
          }

          // reveal the active accordion bodies
          $('.js-accordion-item.active').find('> .js-accordion-body').show();
        },
        toggle: function ($this) {
          if (
            settings.oneOpen &&
            $this[0] !=
              $this
                .closest('.js-accordion')
                .find('> .js-accordion-item.active > .js-accordion-header')[0]
          ) {
            $this
              .closest('.js-accordion')
              .find('> .js-accordion-item')
              .removeClass('active')
              .find('.js-accordion-body')
              .slideUp();
          }

          // show/hide the clicked accordion item
          $this.closest('.js-accordion-item').toggleClass('active');
          $this.next().stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);
        },
      };
    })();

    $(document).ready(function () {
      accordion.init({ speed: 300, oneOpen: true });
    });

    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
      if ($('.tabs')[0]) {
        $('.tabs').each(function () {
          var thisTab = $(this);

          // Intial Border Position
          var activePos = thisTab.find('.tabs-header .active').position();

          function changePos() {
            // Update Position
            activePos = thisTab.find('.tabs-header .active').position();

            // Change Position & Width
            thisTab
              .find('.tab-hover')
              .stop()
              .css({
                left: activePos.left,
                width: thisTab.find('.tabs-header .active').width(),
              });
          }

          changePos();

          // Intial Tab Height
          var tabHeight = thisTab.find('.tab.active').outerHeight();

          // Animate Tab Height
          function animateTabHeight() {
            // Update Tab Height
            tabHeight = thisTab.find('.tab.active').outerHeight();

            // Animate Height
            thisTab
              .find('.tabs-content')
              .stop()
              .css({
                height: tabHeight + 'px',
              });
          }

          animateTabHeight();

          // Change Tab
          function changeTab() {
            var getTabId = thisTab
              .find('.tabs-header .active a')
              .attr('data-tab-id');

            // Remove Active State
            thisTab
              .find('.tab')
              .stop()
              .fadeOut(300, function () {
                // Remove Class
                $(this).removeClass('active');
              })
              .hide();

            thisTab
              .find('.tab[data-tab-id=' + getTabId + ']')
              .stop()
              .fadeIn(300, function () {
                // Add Class
                $(this).addClass('active');

                // Animate Height
                animateTabHeight();
              });
          }

          // Tabs
          thisTab.find('.tabs-header a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Tab Id
            var tabId = $(this).attr('data-tab-id');

            // Remove Active State
            thisTab
              .find('.tabs-header a')
              .stop()
              .parent()
              .removeClass('active');

            // Add Active State
            $(this).stop().parent().addClass('active');

            changePos();

            // Update Current Itm
            tabCurrentItem = tabItems.filter('.active');

            // Remove Active State
            thisTab
              .find('.tab')
              .stop()
              .fadeOut(300, function () {
                // Remove Class
                $(this).removeClass('active');
              })
              .hide();

            // Add Active State
            thisTab
              .find('.tab[data-tab-id="' + tabId + '"]')
              .stop()
              .fadeIn(300, function () {
                // Add Class
                $(this).addClass('active');

                // Animate Height
                animateTabHeight();
              });
          });

          // Tab Items
          var tabItems = thisTab.find('.tabs-header ul li');

          // Tab Current Item
          var tabCurrentItem = tabItems.filter('.active');

          // Next Button
          thisTab.find('.tab-next').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var nextItem = tabCurrentItem.next();

            tabCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

            if (nextItem.length) {
              tabCurrentItem = nextItem.addClass('active');
            } else {
              tabCurrentItem = tabItems.first().addClass('active');
            }

            changePos();
            changeTab();
          });

          // Prev Button
          thisTab.find('.tab-prev').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var prevItem = tabCurrentItem.prev();

            tabCurrentItem.removeClass('active');

            if (prevItem.length) {
              tabCurrentItem = prevItem.addClass('active');
            } else {
              tabCurrentItem = tabItems.last().addClass('active');
            }

            changePos();
            changeTab();
          });
        });
      }
    });




    // Thousand Separator
    function ThousandSeparator(nStr) {
      nStr += '';
      var x = nStr.split('.');
      var x1 = x[0];
      var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }
      return x1 + x2;
    }

    // Bidding Slider Average Value
    var avgValue =
      (parseInt($('.bidding-slider').attr('data-slider-min')) +
        parseInt($('.bidding-slider').attr('data-slider-max'))) /
      2;
    if ($('.bidding-slider').data('slider-value') === 'auto') {
      $('.bidding-slider').attr({ 'data-slider-value': avgValue });
    }

    // Bidding Slider Init
    $('.bidding-slider').slider();

    $('.bidding-slider').on('slide', function (slideEvt) {
      $('#biddingVal').text(ThousandSeparator(parseInt(slideEvt.value)));
    });
    $('#biddingVal').text(
      ThousandSeparator(parseInt($('.bidding-slider').val()))
    );

    // Default Bootstrap Range Slider
    var currencyAttr = $('.range-slider').attr('data-slider-currency');

    $('.range-slider').slider({
      formatter: function (value) {
        return (
          currencyAttr +
          ThousandSeparator(parseInt(value[0])) +
          ' - ' +
          currencyAttr +
          ThousandSeparator(parseInt(value[1]))
        );
      },
    });

    $('.range-slider-single').slider();

    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('.payment-tab-trigger > input');

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
      radios[i].addEventListener('change', expandAccordion);
    }

    function expandAccordion(event) {
      /* jshint validthis: true */
      var tabber = this.closest('.payment');
      var allTabs = tabber.querySelectorAll('.payment-tab');
      for (var i = 0; i < allTabs.length; i++) {
        allTabs[i].classList.remove('payment-tab-active');
      }
      event.target.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('payment-tab-active');
    }

    $('.billing-cycle-radios').on('click', function () {
      if ($('.billed-yearly-radio input').is(':checked')) {
        $('.pricing-plans-container').addClass('billed-yearly');
      }
      if ($('.billed-monthly-radio input').is(':checked')) {
        $('.pricing-plans-container').removeClass('billed-yearly');
      }
    });

    function qtySum() {
      var arr = document.getElementsByName('qtyInput');
      var tot = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(arr[i].value)) tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
      }
    }
    qtySum();

    $('.qtyDec, .qtyInc').on('click', function () {
      var $button = $(this);
      var oldValue = $button.parent().find('input').val();

      if ($button.hasClass('qtyInc')) {
        $button
          .parent()
          .find('input')
          .val(parseFloat(oldValue) + 1);
      } else {
        if (oldValue > 1) {
          $button
            .parent()
            .find('input')
            .val(parseFloat(oldValue) - 1);
        } else {
          $button.parent().find('input').val(1);
        }
      }

      qtySum();
      $('.qtyTotal').addClass('rotate-x');
    });


    /* global ClipboardJS */
    $('.copy-url input').val(window.location.href);
    new ClipboardJS('.copy-url-button');

    $('.share-buttons-icons a').each(function () {
      var buttonBG = $(this).attr('data-button-color');
      if (buttonBG !== undefined) {
        $(this).css('background-color', buttonBG);
      }
    });

    var $tabsNav = $('.popup-tabs-nav'),
      $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li');

    $tabsNav.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this
        .next()
        .children('.popup-tab-content')
        .stop(true, true)
        .hide()
        .first()
        .show();
      $this.children('li').first().addClass('active').stop(true, true).show();
    });

    $tabsNavLis.on('click', function (e) {
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

      $this
        .parent()
        .next()
        .children('.popup-tab-content')
        .stop(true, true)
        .hide()
        .siblings($this.find('a').attr('href'))
        .fadeIn();

      e.preventDefault();
    });

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('.tabs-nav a[href="' + hash + '"]');
    if (anchor.length === 0) {
      $('.popup-tabs-nav li:first').addClass('active').show(); //Activate first tab
      $('.popup-tab-content:first').show(); //Show first tab content
    } else {
      anchor.parent('li').click();
    }

    // Link to Register Tab
    $('.register-tab').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.popup-tab-content').hide();
      $('#register.popup-tab-content').show();
      $('body')
        .find('.popup-tabs-nav a[href="#register"]')
        .parent('li')
        .click();
    });

    // Disable tabs if there's only one tab
    $('.popup-tabs-nav').each(function () {
      var listCount = $(this).find('li').length;
      if (listCount < 2) {
        $(this).css({
          'pointer-events': 'none',
        });
      }
    });


    $('.indicator-bar').each(function () {
      var indicatorLenght = $(this).attr('data-indicator-percentage');
      $(this)
        .find('span')
        .css({
          width: indicatorLenght + '%',
        });
    });


    var uploadButton = {
      $button: $('.uploadButton-input'),
      $nameField: $('.uploadButton-file-name'),
    };

    uploadButton.$button.on('change', function () {
      _populateFileField($(this));
    });

    function _populateFileField($button) {
      var selectedFile = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $button.get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        selectedFile.push($button.get(0).files[i].name + '<br>');
      }
      uploadButton.$nameField.html(selectedFile);
    }


    $('.default-slick-carousel').slick({
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1292,
          settings: {
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 993,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 769,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    $('.testimonial-carousel').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '30%',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1600,
          settings: {
            centerPadding: '21%',
            slidesToShow: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 993,
          settings: {
            centerPadding: '15%',
            slidesToShow: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 769,
          settings: {
            centerPadding: '5%',
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    $('.logo-carousel').slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1365,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 5,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 992,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    });


    $('.mfp-gallery-container').each(function () {
      // the containers for all your galleries

      $(this).magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: 'a.mfp-gallery',

        fixedContentPos: true,
        fixedBgPos: true,

        overflowY: 'auto',

        closeBtnInside: false,
        preloader: true,

        removalDelay: 0,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',

        gallery: { enabled: true, tCounter: '' },
      });
    });

    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',

      fixedContentPos: false,
      fixedBgPos: true,

      overflowY: 'auto',

      closeBtnInside: true,
      preloader: false,

      midClick: true,
      removalDelay: 300,
      mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    });

    $('.mfp-image').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      image: {
        verticalFit: true,
      },
    });

    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
      disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,

      fixedContentPos: false,
    });

  });
})(this.jQuery);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you say something doesn't work, you have to provide details. Using `forceRefresh` for animations is very bad

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have a jQuery file with all functions to make the menu active, for example, if you click on an item of the dashboard it adds a class and the opens another submenu with animation, or the counters increase from zero to whatever the count, all this is not happening, my major problem is that when I goBack the menu doesn’t work. I know forceRefresh is not the best approach but I don’t know how to keep jquery alive, and I don’t have time and the knowledge enough to convert all jQuery file.

Comment: You don't need to stop using jQuery, but when language like "a jQuery file", it is hard no to picture a complete mess. You don't need a refresh to make any of those things happen and jQuery **_does_** remain alive. Sounds like you have bugs that you do not have time to address. That's a fair tradeoff perhaps, but it makes it hard to provide assistance.

Comment: I didn't say that I have bugs I don't have time to address, I said that I don't have time to transform from jquery to ES6. Anyways, I'm adding the whole JQuery, maybe this can help, as far as bugs, I don't see any bug in my React app console, so that's why where the issue reside.